# How to set global variables in template page?

Tags: functions, templates

I know this works.
In `functions.php` do:

```
$variable = "value";
```

and in `header.php` use:

```
global $variable;
echo $variable;
```

Is it possible to set a global variable in template page or include php file?

Comment: My pleasure, take a look at [help: formatting](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to learn more about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anywhere in your script, you can define a global variable as follow:

Using the superglobal `$GLOBALS` array. This array is predefined by PHP, and **is available in all scopes.**

It's an associate array, containing all global variables as a key-value pair.
ie: the key will be the variable name, and value will be the value of the variable.

```
$GLOBALS['variablename'] = 'variablevalue';
```

And it can be accessed as:

```
$variable = $GLOBALS['variablename'];
```

or

```
global $variable;
```

to know more ref: [PHP Variable Scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

**EDIT:** While answering i assumed the user knew about method 2, but on rereading it seems maybe he is not aware of it, so am mentioning it below.

Method 2:

you can define global variable using the 'global' keyword as well.
eg code:

//file1.php

```
class testScope()
{
   function setMsg($msg = 'Hi')
  {
    //the variable need not be already defined in the global scope. 
   global $say;
   $say = 'Hi';
  }

  function say()
  {
    global $say;
    echo $say;
  } 
}

//file2.php 

function getFile1()
{
  include('file1.php');
}

getFile1();

$sayer = new testScope();

$sayer->setMsg(); // this will create a new global variable. 
$sayer->say();
global $say; 
echo $say; 

$say = "I changed it in global scope";

$sayer->say(); // 'I changed it in global scope'

$sayer->set('i changed it inside class');
echo $say; // ' i changed it inside class'
```

**Note: The code is untested**